# Mongoose find() to check if any of the value matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am getting name and address from req.body

```
const {name, address} = req.body;
```

I am using Mongoose.find to check if the name and address already exists in my database.

- If name matches, check for address. If address also matches, do nothing.
- If name matches, check for address. If address does not match, update address with the new one.
- If name does not match, create a new entry in the database.

I approached this in the following way.

```
Token.find({$or: [{name, address}]}, (err, existingName) => {
  if ( *name matches*) {
    if ( *address matches* ) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
    // If address does not match.
    // Update address
  }
  // If name does not match
  // Create a new entry
}
```

**Problem**

- If name is match and address is not match, it is creating a new entry. It is not updating.

Is my approach wrong or is there a better approach? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand what this line will do.

```
Token.find({$or: [{name, address}]}, (err, existingName) => { }
```

This line is equivalent to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE NAME=NAME OR ADDRESS=ADDRESS
```

Now, this is not what you are trying to achieve. You want to check if the name exists and then address exists for that name. So, your approach will fail.

**New Approach: Use Promise or Async/Await**
In your case, you will query for the name (pause for some time), and query for address. So, do something like:

```
let findName = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Token.findOne({name})
    .exec(function(err, data) {
      // Handle error.
      // Resolve or Reject
      })
    })
 }

let findAddress = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Token.findOne({address})
    .exec(function(err, data) {
      // Handle error.
      // Resolve or Reject
      })
    })
 }
```

Now consume that Promise.

```
findName().then(findAddress).then(() => {
  if(//name exists) {
    if(//address exists) {
      // Do nothing
    }
    // Update address
  }
  else {
    // Create new entry
  }
})
```